# Ctrl + Shift + L not recognized by visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

VS 2017 does not recognize Ctrl + Shift + L at all. Most other key combos are working. If I open Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, focus the "Press shortcut keys:" field and press Ctrl + Shift + L, it stays empty. Every other key combo gets displayed.

Ctrl + Shift + L works in other applications so I guess it is a VS problem. Typing key combos using osk.exe has the same effect.

I could rebind the command behind Ctrl + Shift + L, but that's not the goal ... i am used to this combo and would like to keep it

I have disabled all extensions (Resharper), but the problem persists.

I tried rebooting, repairing, and completely reinstalling (removing and then installing again)

Ctrl + Shift + O is also not working. Could not identify others yet.

Everything was working before today. I have not changed anything today besides some Resharper settings and a resharper update. Since I reinstalled and disabled resharper, this shouldn't be the problem though?

Other data:

- Keyboard Layout: German
- OS: Windows 10
- VS Community: 15.5.6

Comment: What is your keyboard layout and which operating do you use? Is it polish?

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT Win 10; German (Germany). I never changed my keyboard layout. I have VS installed since months, it always worked before today.

Comment: Any clue as to why I am getting downvoted? I have clearly isolated the problem to my VS2017 installtion and provided as much info as possible ...

Comment: Pfeifen ... Try it without shortcut. Go to the menu, I will explain based on your language: Anzeigen » Befehlspalette... » Then type "Alle Vorkommen auswählen und Übereinkommen ...". Does this workaround work?

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT I am having a hard time doing that as my OS and all my programs are in english ... I'm only using the german layout. I guess you want me to go to View >> ... but I'm not finding a possible translation for Befehlspalette

Comment: Should be the first in the row. Shortcut is CTRL + Shift + P

Comment: Then type "Select all Occurences of Find Match"

Comment: Ok, guys, i've seen it and this does not look like a configuration error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> are Hotkeys for some AMD Drivers to change settings while gaming. Make sure you have disabled them.

Comment: To elaborate on this, the new "Adrenalin" series of AMD Radeon software (driver, etc) added some overlays that can be (in games!) globally invoked with these key combos. (Using keyboard hooks) In other apps the keys are just blocked. The other application where I checked to make sure it's VS's fault apparently also uses Keyboardhooks, so it worked there ...

Comment: AMD Settings > Gaming > Global Settings > Performance Monitoring > Toggle Performance Logging Hotkey > "Delete" key

Comment: That could be _any other_ application catching this combination, just do some investigation. In my case it was Download Manager.